# Log4Net error when process starts

Tags: log4net

I'm using Log4Net in my code, but it throws an exception when my process is run.  I'm using this configuration:

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppenderXml" />
  </root>
  <appender name="FileAppenderXml" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="logs\%date{yyyy}\%date{MM}\%date{yyyyMMdd}.xml"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j">
      <locationInfo value="true"/>
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <param name="Encoding" value="utf-8" />
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

And the exception is:

> log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Cannot find Property [conversionPattern] to set object on [log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j]

Answer (score 0):

The `conversionPattern` is a property on the `PatternLayout` layout, and isn't available on the `XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j` layout.  Simply remove it:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j">
    <locationInfo value="true"/>
</layout>
```

The `XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j` layout can be slightly customised with [its own properties](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Layout_XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j.htm).